# Не работает Git LFS в Hugging Face Spaces

Tags: git, git-lfs

После того, как я начал использовать Git LFS в Hugging Face Spaces, сборка перестала работать.

```
--> ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c git init  && git remote add origin $(cat /run/secrets/SPACE_REPOSITORY)  && git add --all  && git config user.email \"name@mail.com\"  && git config user.name \"Name\"  && git commit -m \"lfs\"  && git lfs pull  && rm -rf .git .gitattributes" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```